# JSP Pass values from a table to a form

Tags: html, sql, database, jsp

I have a page with some details of product, i need to edit the  current details, so i want to pass these row current values to an edit page when the edit button is clicked.
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 Methods to pass values from one jsp to another.
With a PathVariable:

```
<a href="site.jsp?var=${var}" />
```

With a hidden field:

```
<form method="post" action="next.jsp">    
   <input type="hidden" name="var" value="${var}">
```

Or with a Session object.

```
session.setAttribute("var", var);
```

You can get this with s`ession.getAttribute(var)` on the next jsp.

Comment: Actually i'm having a page with some rows and each row has an edit button. I need to edit each row items. so i need to pass the whole row contents when i click the edit button on that row.

Comment: So you can store all the cells in the same var or use a var for each cell. However, it seems your problem is solved bc you marked the answer